# How to replace character in String[] array

Tags: java, string, swing

I'm building a Java swing application.
I write a custom defaultTableModel class, this is the code:

```
public class MyTableModelScontriniArticoli extends defaultTableModel {
    private static final String[] columnNames = {"Cod.Prod.", "Descrizione", "Qta","Prezzo cad.","Sconto $$","Prezzo Tot"};
    public HashMap<String, ArticoliScontrini> mappaArticoli = new HashMap<String, ArticoliScontrini>();
    
    public Boolean gestisciTagliaColore;
    private Boolean consentiModificaDescrizione;
    private String tipologiaSconto;
    
    //public MyTableModelScontriniArticoli() {}


    public MyTableModelScontriniArticoli(boolean gestisciTagliaColore, boolean consentiModificaDescrizione,
            String tipologiaSconto) {
        super(columnNames, 1);    // 10 righe iniziali (vuote)
        mappaArticoli = new HashMap<String, ArticoliScontrini>();
    }

    public MyTableModelScontriniArticoli(String[] columnnames2, int i) {
        super(columnnames2, 1);    // 10 righe iniziali (vuote)
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        //  return columnIndex == 1;    // Solo la prima colonna ï¿½ editabile
        if(this.getConsentiModificaDescrizione()!=null && 
                this.getConsentiModificaDescrizione())
            return (columnIndex > 0 && columnIndex <= 4);
        else
            return (columnIndex > 1 && columnIndex <= 4);
    }   
}
```

Now I need the replate the "$$" character in "columnNames" array with string in "tipologiaSconto".

How can I do this?

Comment: Even if the array is final, that doesnt mean you cant change the contents of the array. Just operate on the string maybe `.replaceAll()` or whatever preferred option you like then reassign new string to correct index of the array

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `replace` method. Note, however, that strings in Java are immutable and this will create a new instance of a string, so make sure you aren't keeping any references to the old one.

```java
columnNames[4] = columnNames[4].replace("$$", tipologiaSconto);
```