# Get screen resolution of monitor where application is still runnning

Tags: java, swing

I build the following java class to get correct size of my java swing application.

With this class I m able to get resolution of my screen and after that I can set correctly the height and width of my java swing components.

So is valid if I run my application on the first monitor of my computer. If I try to start the application on the second monitor the class get the resolution of the first screen.

This is my class to calculate the resolution of the screen:

package com.mcsolution.common.Componenti_Swing;

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class Dimensione extends Dimension {
    Dimension screenSize;
    double larghezza,altezza;
    public Dimensione(){
        Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        screenSize = t.getScreenSize();
        double width = screenSize.getWidth();
        double height= screenSize.getHeight()*0.9;
        this.setSize(width, height);
    }
    
    

    /********PANEL******************/
    public Dimension DimensionePanel(){
        larghezza = screenSize.getWidth();
        altezza = screenSize.getHeight()*0.95;
        //   System.out.println("Pannello la larghezza Ã¯Â¿Â½ " + width + "la larghezza Ã¯Â¿Â½ " + larghezza);
        this.setSize(larghezza,altezza);
        return this;
    }
    
    public Dimension PanelArticoliScontrini(){
        larghezza = screenSize.getWidth();
        altezza = screenSize.getHeight()*0.65;
        //   System.out.println("Pannello la larghezza Ã¯Â¿Â½ " + width + "la larghezza Ã¯Â¿Â½ " + larghezza);
        this.setSize(larghezza,altezza);
        return this;
    }
    
    public Dimension PanelArticoliDaStampare(){
        larghezza = screenSize.getWidth();
        altezza = screenSize.getHeight()*0.90;
        //   System.out.println("Pannello la larghezza Ã¯Â¿Â½ " + width + "la larghezza Ã¯Â¿Â½ " + larghezza);
        this.setSize(larghezza,altezza);
        return this;
    }
    
}
```

There is a way to detect in which monitor the application is running and get the screen size?

Comment: 1) Don't extend Dimension. You are not providing any new functionality to the Dimension class. 2) Why are you trying to set the width/height of components? That is the job of the layout manager. 3) See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77818751/how-to-replace-character-in-string-array

Comment: I need to detect the screen resolution of monitor that are showing the Java swing application

Comment: Perhaps see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1248477/4725875).

Comment: (1-) @bircastri *I need to detect the screen resolution* - yes, but you have another question with an answer that you haven't yet accepted or given a comment if the answer doesn't work. Don't expect people to keep helping if you can't acknowledge previous help given.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jframe.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice();` to get the device.

Then use `device.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();` to get the resolution.

Here's a working example:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Demo {

    private Demo() {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Test");

        // Get the current device
        GraphicsDevice device = jframe.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice();

        // get the resolution of the device
        Rectangle r = device.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
        String s = "Device: " + device.getIDstring() +  "\nResolution: " + r.width + "x" + r.height;

        jframe.add(new JTextArea(s), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.pack();
        jframe.setSize(400,300);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Demo();
            }
        });
    }

}
```